# Does sp_Blitz @BringThePain parameter cause pain for the user (delay) or the server (blocking/slowing production workload)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sp-blitz

I want to run sp_Blitz and other scripts (from first aid) on a busy primary production server.

There are 75 databases on the server, of which 40 are in an availability group (synchronous, no read scale).

I am reading the readme file which says `@BringThePain = 1 - required if you want to run @CheckUserDatabaseObjects = 1 with over 50 databases. It's gonna be slow.`

The term pain is scary and so I want to ask whether the pain is in terms of the time that I have to wait to get the response from the stored proc or does pain mean that its going to cause blocking/slow production workload on the sql server?

Comment: The queries will take resources to run, but they don't do anything that should cause locks/blocking on your user databases. It's mostly, as far as I can tell, about the time you'll have to wait. Unless your server is regularly out of CPU resources it should just be you inconvenienced by it.

Comment: This is available in [the documentation](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/main/README.md#sp_blitz-overall-health-check). _@BringThePain = 1 - required if you want to run @CheckUserDatabaseObjects = 1 with over 50 databases. It's gonna be slow._

Comment: Yes I have seen that but wanted to be sure because the word `pain` didn't sound quite nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will slow down both its own session, plus add additional overhead to the server.

There's no way to add load to one person without also affecting other users on the server.